# Should I activate the Golden Switch after activating an Elder Frenzy?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Immediately after activating Elder Frenzy, I usually click like a mad man.

But today I thought, "Maybe I should be activating the Golden Switch in order to maximise Elder Frenzy effectiveness..."

Does the benefit of the Golden Switch out-way the cost of activating and deactivating it?

It should be noted I am towards the end-game with Elder Spice, Residual Luck & Get Lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, activating the golden switch stops any currently running frenzies, including Elder Frenzy.

Comment: Also, the price of the Golden Switch is 666x more expensive.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a thing as well. So not only would it *cost* you an hour worth of 666x production, you wouldn't get the 14 seconds off it you'd normally get